# Set of Cluster Points

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,T)$ is a topological space
How can I prove the set of cluster points closed?
Found all the proofs on metric spaces but couldn't relate them to this

Comment: What is the definition of cluster point you are using?

Comment: @WilliamElliot x is limot point of A then for every V neighborhood of x, V $\cap$ A-{x} is non empty

Answer (score 1):

If A is a subset of a T1 space S, then
A' (the limit points of is A) is closed.
A space is T1 when all singletons are closed.

To show S - A' is open, assume x in S - A'.
Thus some open U with x in U and empty U ∩ {A - {x}).

If y in U, y /= x, then y in S\A'. Proof:
y in open U - {x}; (U - {x}) ∩ (A - {y}) is empty; y not in A'.
As x in S - A', altogether U subset S - A' and S - A' is open.

Notice that only T1 is needed to show A' is closed. 
For other spaces there is the theorem
(for all x, {x}' is closed) iff (for all A, A' is closed).